# How to derive types from the passed arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with a `methods` parameter and its type definitions come from an imported library.

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface FormParams  {
  commonField: string
  optionalField1: string
  optionalField2: number
}

function App() {
  const methods = useForm<FormParams >();
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = methods

  useCustomHook({ methods, optionalFieldName: 'optionalField2' })
}
```

In this component, I call a function which expects this `methods` parameter and the name of one of the optional form parameters as arguments.

And here's the implementation for this function;

```js
import { FieldPath, FieldValues, useForm, UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";

type CustomFieldValues = FieldValues & {
  commonField: string
}

type HookParams = {
  methods: UseFormReturn<CustomFieldValues>
  optionalFieldName?: FieldPath<CustomFieldValues>
}

const useCustomHook = ({ methods, optionalFieldName = 'optionalField1' }: HookParams) => {
  const { watch } = methods
  const fieldValue = watch(optionalFieldName) // ❌ returns with type `any` because of wrong typing
  const commonFieldValue = watch('commonField') // ✅ returns with correct `string` type

  // do some stuff
}
```

The types for the function is not complete. In here `watch` function returns the current value for the given form parameter name. Currently, `commonFieldValue` is correctly typed as `string` but `fieldValue` typed as `any`.

If I were to be able to use `UseFormReturn<FormParams>` for `methods` I wouldn't have this problem but this function is actually being called from a lot of components with different form parameters. Only parameter that is common is `commonField`. And the other field is based on the argument passed to the function. This code may look useless but I tried to simplify it as much as possible to focus on the problem.

So if I call the function with;

```js
useCustomHook({ methods, optionalFieldName: 'optionalField2' })
```

this `fieldValue` parameter should be typed as `number`.

```js
const fieldValue = watch(optionalFieldName)
```

if I call the function with;

```js
useCustomHook({ methods })
```

this `fieldValue` parameter should be typed as `string` (because default value is `optionalField1`).

```js
const fieldValue = watch(optionalFieldName)
```

Can we define a generic type for HookParams so I can get the correct type definition inside the function?

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-type-issue-o7ujgy?file=/src/index.tsx) for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this 100% type safe. The way `UseFormReturn` it is invariant (so there is no inheritance relationship between `UseFormReturn<CustomFieldValues>` and `UseFormReturn<FormParams>`, see my talk on variance [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU))

You can however use to more relaxed checking of assignability when it comes to overloads. So we will have a public function signature that allows us to pass in the derived type and an implementation signature that will use `UseFormReturn<CustomFieldValues>`. Now I want to stress this will not be 100% type safe, you might be able to do things that you should be allowed, but this is as good it's going to get

```
function useCustomHook<T extends CustomFieldValues>(args: HookParams<T>): void
function useCustomHook({ methods, optionalFieldName = 'optionalField1' }: HookParams<CustomFieldValues & Record<string, unknown>>) {
  const { watch } = methods
  const fieldValue = watch(optionalFieldName) // We don't know what type the field will have so we get unknown (from & Record<string, unknown>)
  const commonFieldValue = watch('commonField') // ✅ returns with correct `string` type
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWAUwDYBMAKBDGACwBoV1sA1PDAVzQGdSb61loRSBVFtqEAJTQwaUAHZwAvnABmUCCDgAiKGjwBjGAFpCECAGtN09ooDcAKDPBRMNFGnq0Kdvih4Q9OIjOe18kBFFUTCwALjh6GCgrAHNvOAgwGGAA6iDsAEYwiKjRWM8EpJSMNKwAJjDRGhAAI1szCQtpGlENZPEAQTAwAAoASi8fAIi4ECEdLA8AXjhmVnYAHl4QFzcPAD4+80HRYaQVaOAI21JCPFEsDDQAZRpqkGAYUgB3AjVCSThp0aIICbjZgDCzBg8gAEro9N0kN9xox4ok2qlyFgAHJuNBhADkvhA-kCyMxkl69QsZhgAE8wI4gRF5CUqLQGJ8BnAcXiSllIjESWTKY5wfoVu55gAVOBoAAeNnOHhpIJA9OodHoa2ZCDiMN+9DC3DmfEEwjEorWcQKiOKyLRowA-GESvgiMaeU0WoVxIDgWCIaLxVK0DK4HK6ciGcqNngoNFtXABXohfRjb0wgA3CDALBmF2tAIzFhBkCxqEjMZa0hmoolK2OaaY8uiJHBdKEiRhWPx+b5xWMjwAMjggl8UCw82yMSYoj0oggT1EazW-XV212cBeMDeHy+Jb+S-g0hDSurK9ehG6dYb2Cr-QA9Fe4AB1RxYAKY+CT6cr07wClUuBERx74IV2ADAMDgU5k0cegIBXRxoiEGYJynGc4G6WR5DgPsB2gYdR1ycc3xnec4l8HZ4DZAIuzoZlVzebpsT8CiCWvW9AFByOAVENHYgKIVloBUDQ4AAA1w6JBN-Pl6iAA)

Note: On the implementation signature I also had to add `Record<string, unknown>`. This is to allow us to index with an arbitrary property that we don't know. This does mean you can call `watch` with any string, but you will get `unknown`, if you call watch with one on the known properties however, you will get the correct type.